# jQuery declare function and call

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
 function showAlert(){
  alert('Bazinga')
 }
$(document).ready(function(){
            showAlert();
        });
</script>
```

In my example I first of all declaring function and else calling this function when documents is loaded. But alert is now show.

Comment: Apart from typo missing `);` at the end of document-ready handler, What is the problem?

Comment: You have an excellent console included in Firefox and in Chrome in which you can quickly check that your code has syntax errors.

Comment: I see no problems; are you sure jQuery is included in the page?  Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: here's a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f7LPX/, so as others have said, your code is fine. Check your developer tools for an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have included jQuery library , The script should be after the jQuery library.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   function showAlert(){
      alert('Bazinga');
   }
   $(document).ready(function(){
       showAlert();
   });
</script>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/NZBbW/)

Comment: While the semicolon is good style, it's not needed in JavaScript, especially for the last statement in a block.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the ";" on alert, try adding ";". If that does not do the trick you could try move up ur document ready.